# ABP Framework smtp password encryption

Tags: abp

ABP Framework https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Settings - I can set:

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "Abp.Mailing.DefaultFromAddress": "noreply@mydomain.com",
    "Abp.Mailing.DefaultFromDisplayName": "My Application",
    "Abp.Mailing.Smtp.Host": "mail.mydomain.com",
    "Abp.Mailing.Smtp.Port": "547",
    "Abp.Mailing.Smtp.UserName": "myusername",
    "Abp.Mailing.Smtp.Password": "mySecretPassW00rd",
    "Abp.Mailing.Smtp.EnableSsl": "True"
  }
}
```

"Abp.Mailing.Smtp.Password": "mySecretPassW00rd" is encrypted, how to encrypt password?

Documentation is very shortly and unusable: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/String-Encryption

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SettingManager` to encrypt your password. You only need to define it in the `OnApplicationInitialization` in your module.

```cs
public class YourProjectDomainModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
        {
            var settingManager = context.ServiceProvider.GetService<SettingManager>();
            //encrypts the password on set and decrypts on get
            settingManager.SetGlobalAsync(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Password, "your_password");
        }
       
      //...

    }
```

- You don't have to define this in your domain module, also, you can define it in any other module.
- You can also check [this article](https://community.abp.io/articles/replacing-email-templates-and-sending-emails-jkeb8zzh).

Answer (score 0):

Use IStringEncryptionService to encrypt your password and set it to Abp.Mailing.Smtp.Password.

Write a separate tool or just instantiate IStringEncryptionService in the Home controller in Host project in debug mode and use

IStringEncryptionService.Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase = null, byte[] salt = null)

to encrpt the password you want to store in "Abp.Mailing.Smtp.Password". passPhrase  is got from appsettings StringEncryption:DefaultPassPhrase, if required you can change this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringEncryptionService to encrypt the passwords used in smtp settings

```
// Default Pass Phrase
var encryptedValue = StringEncryptionService.Encrypt(value);

// Custom Pass Phrase
var encryptedValue = StringEncryptionService.Encrypt(value, "MyCustomPassPhrase");
```

---

```
// Default Salt
var encryptedValue = StringEncryptionService.Encrypt(value);

// Custom Salt
var encryptedValue = StringEncryptionService.Encrypt(value, salt: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyCustomSalt")); 

// Encrypt & Decrypt have same parameters.
var decryptedValue = StringEncryptionService.Decrypt(value,  salt: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyCustomSalt"));


// Encrypt & Decrypt have same parameters.
var decryptedValue = StringEncryptionService.Decrypt(value, "MyCustomPassPhrase");
```

---

```
Configure<AbpStringEncryptionOptions>(opts =>
{
    opts.DefaultPassPhrase = "MyStrongPassPhrase";
    opts.DefaultSalt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyStrongSalt");
    opts.InitVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("YetAnotherStrongSalt");
    opts.Keysize = 512;
});
```

ref: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/String-Encryption